# Fixing random seed on inference

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, inference, prediction, randomness

I will be deploying models into production and I'm wondering whether it is appropriate to fix the random number generator seed at inference time. Here's what I think:

- setting the seed will give consistent results (assume model is trained and deployed on same device, as device can also affect randomness)
- if i need to set the seed to get good results, that means my model does not generalize well (hence, i should retrain model until seed does not have a significant effect on performance)

I hope anyone can provide me with suggestions or insights. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not simply generate the seed based on the system time and store the seed in a database or system log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three points

- It's not impossible that one seed value gives a model that honestly generalises better, because (for example) there's an important high-order interaction that is only seen when exactly the right set of features is subsampled. Stranger things have happened (but not much stranger, and not very often)
- Much more often (as you note) if the seed matters you have a problem, and it's worth at least attempting to train the sensitivity out of the model
- However, even if the seed doesn't make any *substantive* difference, it it is always useful and sometimes important to be able to prove that a particular decision was taken in a particular way. Most often this is true for debugging, but sometimes it's true because someone is accusing you/your client/your employer of cheating and not actually using the model you say you used.